# All blocks should come horizontally

Tags: html, css

In the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Qv9uQ/

I want all the block 1 , block 2,block 3 ,block 4 in same line.My table position have to fixed.It should not change I tried with display:inline-block.it is not working.

If i keep table position fixed and set the margins table positioning is also changing..but my table have to fixed.

You can try the below code by running in fiddle:

```
<div class="Box"  style="width: 15%; height: 67; overflow-n: scroll; display: inline-block;scrollbar-arrow-color: blue;
    scrollbar-face-color: #e7e7e7; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #a0a0a0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #888888">
        block 1
</div><br/>

<TABLE CLASS="BODY" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" RULES="NONE"> table 1 </TABLE>

    <div style="width: 20%; height: 67;display: inline-block;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: blue; scrollbar-face-color: #e7e7e7;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #a0a0a0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #888888">
       block 2
</div> <br/> 

    <table CLASS="BODY" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" RULES="NONE" > table 2</table>

    <div style="width: 22%; height: 67;  display: inline-block;
         scrollbar-arrow-color: blue; scrollbar-face-color: #e7e7e7;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #a0a0a0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #888888">
        block 3
    </div><br/>

        <table CLASS="BODY" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" RULES="NONE" > table 3</table>

    <div style="width: 25%; height: 67; display: inline-block;
         scrollbar-arrow-color: blue; scrollbar-face-color: #e7e7e7;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #a0a0a0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #888888">
        block 4
    </div><br/>​

 <table CLASS="BODY" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" RULES="NONE" > table 4</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you can't change the order of your HTML, you'll need to use absolute positioning on the `<divs>`. Give each `<div>` an `id` and set `left` for each one and `top: 0;`

*Demo:* http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/sZQNc/

#### CSS:

```html
<style>
    div {
        top: 0; 
        position: absolute; 
    }
    
    #block1 {
        left: 0;   
    }
    
    ​#block2 {
        left: 25%;    
    }
    
    #block3 {
        left: 50%;    
    }
    
    ​#block4 {
        left: 75%    
    }​
</style>
```